# Inserting barcode into document when it creates

Tags: document-library, properties, quick-parts, barcodes

I am using SharePoint online (office 365).

As you know, you can add the value of fields(Site columns) from a Document library into a document by using Quick Parts. I have manged to add Barcode field to the Document library (by going to "Information management and policy settings" of the Library). I can see the generated barcode in the view for a particular item (document). However I cannot add a quick part for the barcode field to the document temaplate of the list, because it does not appear in the list of queck parts to add when you edit the word template of the library.

How can I add the generated barcode to the document?

Answer (score 1):

See [Discontinued features and modified functionality in Microsoft SharePoint 2013](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Microsoft-SharePoint-2013-bbbb0815-2538-4f1d-b647-1f7f6d508c93):

> Insert Barcode command is no longer available on the ribbon. The
> functionality of requiring SharePoint generated barcodes to be
> embedded in a Microsoft Word document has been discontinued
>
> Workaround: Write a custom Open XML application that takes the server side barcode and injects into the Word document.
>
> Applies to: SharePoint Server 2013, SharePoint Online 2013

Since you are using O365, there is some chance to find a suitable App in Office Store.